# Наложение JComponent

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет. Подскажите: возможно ли создание двух JComponent-ов с графикой наложенных друг на друга, чтобы при этом была видна графическая часть обоих компонентов. 
Наведите плз на какой нить русскоязычный источник. А то спецификацию на английском с трудом перевариваю. Особенно в тех местах где даже на русском бы не понял) Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выставляете [setOpaque(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque-boolean-)(непрозрачность), ну и рисуете цветом с прозрачностью, картинкой с прозрачностью, либо просто ничего не рисуете в нужных вам местах.

Когда это свойство равно false, перекрывающиеся регионы компонентов отрисовывается на всех "слоях". В противном же случае(true - по умолчанию), при перекрытии будет отрисовывается регион только самого верхнего компонента.